# How to get a handle on all this middleware?

Tags: soa, esb, middleware, business-process-management

My organization has recently been wrestling the question of whether we should be incorporating different middleware products / concepts into our applications.  Products we are looking at are things like Pegasystems, Oracle BPM / BPEL, BizTalk, Fair Isaac Blaze, etc., etc., etc.

But I'm having a hard time getting a handle on all this.  Before I go forward with evaluating the usefulness (positive or negative) of these different products I'm trying to get an understanding of all the different concepts in this space.  I'm overwhelmed with an alphabet soup of BPM, ESB, SOA, CEP, WF, BRE, ERP, etc.  Some products seem to cover one or more of those aspects, others focus on doing one.  The terms all seem very ambiguous and conflated with each other.

Is there a good resource out there to get a handle on all these different middleware concepts / patterns?  A book?  A website?  An article that sums it up well?  Bonus points if there is a resource that maps the various popular products into which pattern(s) they address.

Thanks,

~ Justin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've spent the last 3-4 years blogging on the topics you mentioned (http://www.UdiDahan.com) as well as writing my own lightweight ESB (http://www.NServiceBus.com) and many more years working and consulting in this space. The main conclusion that I've come to is that strong business analysis and technologically-agnostic architecture is needed - no tool or technology can prevent a mess by itself.

There is the Enterprise Integration Patterns book which provides a good catalog of the technical patterns involved but doesn't touch on the necessary business analysis. I've found that Value Networks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_network_analysis) can be used as a good start for identifying business boundaries to which IT boundaries can be then aligned, resulting in the benefits of SOA, and the use of an ESB across those boundaries is justified.

CEP, WF, and BRE should be used within a boundary and not across them.

ERP packages tend to cross boundaries and, as such, should be integrated piecemeal into the boundaries mentioned - DDD anti-corruption layers can be used to insulate custom logic from those apps.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thx for the response Udi.  I have read some of your articles and have heard you interviewed before.  I definitely appreciate your input.  I will check out the resources you mention.

Answer (score 0):

IBM and Oracle have SOA certifications. Since they're the leaders in the marketplace (Gartner Magic Quadrant), I would read about how they define SOA and ESBs (along with methodology and the components needed to support SOA like Governance, Registry, etc etc).   It'll give you the high level overview that you're looking for and the use cases "all this middleware" is trying to solve.